# JavaScript function chaining using the singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, chaining

I have a small piece of code written like in below.

```
var MY = MY || {};

MY.Farm = (function () {

    var add = function(x){
        console.log(x)
        return this + this;
    };

    return {
        add: function(x){
            return add(x);
        }

    }
});
```

On a separate file I create `sheep` an instance of `MY.Farm`

```
var sheep = new MY.Farm()
```

I want to be able to call the function like the following with an output `6`

```
sheep.add(3).add(2).add(1)
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? What are the changes required to the `MY.Farm` snippet to accommodate this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: me thinks add var x; in the My.Fram function and then  remove the "new" from creating the sheep, the x will stay in the closure as hidden variable. In the add check if x has been set and return this; to allow chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var MY = MY || {};

MY.Farm = (function () {
    var x=0;
    return {
        add: function(newX){
            if(typeof(newX) !="undefined") {
                x+=newX;
                return this;
            }
            return x;
       }
    }
});

var sheep = MY.Farm();
console.log( sheep.add(2).add(4).add());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7q0143er/

Answer (score 1):

You're not too far off. The trick is you need to keep track of the value somewhere, like in a private variable, and `add` needs to return `this`. Finally, you need a way to get the value out when you're done:

```
MY.Farm = function () {
    var total = 0;

    return {
        add: function(x) {
          total += x;
          return this;
        },

        value: function() {
          return total;
        }
    };
};

var sheep = new MY.Farm();

sheep.add(3);
console.log(sheep.value()); // => 3

console.log(sheep.add(1).add(2).value()); // => 6
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, Tried out @Tero Tolonen answer first and it worked straight away. So had to accept his. Thanks a lot for your answer.